# On AWS do I have to open ports in an EC2 instance's firewall as well as security group?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, iptables, redhat, amazon-web-services

If I change my SSH port from 22 to 23453, I can no longer ssh in.

In more detail, I'm using a Red Hat EC2 instance on Amazon Web Services. This is the second change I've on a fresh install (first change was to add a non-root user).

I can ssh in fine using Git Bash and a local .ssh/config file, I edit the line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config that currently says

```
#Port 23453
```

to say

```
Port 23453
```

then restart sshd with

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

I then add a line "Port 23453" my .ssh/config file

```
Host foo 
Hostname my-ec2-public-DNS
Port 23453
IdentityFile my ssl key
```

If I open another Git Bash shell (without closing my existing connection) and attempt to ssh into my instance (with ssh foo) I see the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host my-ec2-public-DNS port 23453: Bad file number
```

The security group attached to this instance has two entries, both TCP

`22 (SSH) 0.0.0.0/0`

`23453 0.0.0.0/0`

My best guess is that the port is still blocked by my firewall.

The output of `sudo iptables -L` is as follows

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Which looks pretty open to me.

**UPDATE**

After adding an iptables rule

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 23453 -j ACCEPT
```

and trying again, still no luck.

Output of `iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:23453

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Which looks sufficiently open. I'm not entirely sure how to look for packets coming in or activity on the port. But the output of `netstat -ntlp` (as root)

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:56137               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      948/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      930/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1012/cupsd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1224/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:23453               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      32638/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::36139                    :::*                        LISTEN      948/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      930/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 ::1:631                     :::*                        LISTEN      1012/cupsd
tcp        0      0 :::23453                    :::*                        LISTEN      32638/sshd
```

Which seems to me to show sshd on 23453.

I've checked again that the instance has the port open in the security group (Port: 23453, Protocol: tcp, Source: 0.0.0.0/0)

What else can be causing the failure to connect via SSH?

Cheers

**POSTMORTEM**

I can now connect. It was a missing rule in iptables. The output of `iptables -L` now looks like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:23453 state NEW
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: For anyone who can't see the difference between the third `iptables -L` (ssh works) and the second `iptables -L` (ssh is blocked). Look at the order of the rules in the INPUT chain (the 6 lines under the first "target"), they're read from top to bottom, so in the second set of rules, "REJECT all" is hit before "ACCEPT tcp dpt:23453". The third set of rules has the ACCEPT entry above, and hence before, the REJECT entry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your instance firewall doesn't have this port open. Try the following command:

```
iptables -I INPUT 3 -s 0.0.0.0/0 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -p tcp --dport 23453 -m state --state New -j ACCEPT
```

Note that iptables rules need to be saved to persist after a reboot. On RHEL that's:

```
/sbin/service iptables save
```

Comment: This worked. If someone could tell me important difference between @melsayed's iptables rule and Frank's iptables rule, I'd be very thankful.

Also, I guess this means the answer to my ultimate question is "Yes, on AWS you do have to open ports in ec2 instance firewalls as well as their security groups". Thanks everyone.

Comment: I tried to comment on Frank's answer but I don't have enough rep yet :)

Comment: Basically, Frank's iptables command adds (-A) a new rule that would allow connection to that port. The problem is, it adds the rule at the end of the iptables list of rules. The last rule in the iptables list rejects anything that's not explicitly allowed before it. Since iptables rules are applied in order, the connection is matched and rejected before even getting to the new rule.

Comment: I inserted a new rule in the list, at the 3rd position (-I INPUT 3). Which is matched before the reject rule at the end, hence allowing the connection. As Frank mentioned, you could use iptables -nvL to see the number of packets matched by each rule, which helps while debugging such configuration.

Comment: `/sbin/service iptables save` isn't working for me, even with sudo.

Comment: @huertanix that would really depend on the distro you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Add an iptables rule

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 23435 -j ACCEPT
```

which accepts traffic from any host, by port 23435, and try to ssh, if you see any packets or activity, then it means that the packets are reaching your server.

If you see no packets, that means that the AWS Security group does not have rule to allow your port.

but if you see traffic on this rule (by `iptables -nvL`), then you have to run "netstat -ntlp" and verify if SSH daemon is running on port 2435. and on `0.0.0.0/0`.

hopefully these steps would resolve the issue. if still no, then tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the security group is set correctly? Did you click "Apply changes"? Many people forget to actually apply their changes :)

"Bad file number" usually signifies connection timeouts, and your iptables setup looks correct.

Comment: I fell foul to the "apply changes" pitfall once before. Never again. :)

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone stumbles across this topic because they changed the default port of ssh, here's a solution that worked out for me:

1. To bypass a corporate firewall, I changed the port to 80 on `/etc/ssh/sshd_conf`.
2. Unfortunately, Apache was already installed on that instance so I could not ssh anymore.
3. I detached the volume from the instance.
4. attached it to another instance
5. mounted it, changed the port in the config file
6. detached it, re attached it on the old instance
7. rebooted: all good :D